# Text to speech web API

Tags: api, text-to-speech

I want a text-speech API that works over the web. Google Translate unofficial API doesn't fit because I need to read more than one paragraph and they're limited to 100 chars.

I checked iSpeech, but they require a telephone call to buy credits and since this work maintainers do not speak english and this type of billing/selling is pretty ridiculous, I'm looking forward for another alternative.

Anyone?

EDIT: It must have an pt-BR voice.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I actually spoke to iSpeech ( http://www.ispeech.org ) the other day, and apparently you can purchase credits directly from the web site (did you click Upgrade?). The reference to having to contact them is regarding higher volume pricing. (I haven't actually upgraded, so I haven't verified this, but that's what they said.)

Alternatives include:

- http://ws.neospeech.com
- http://acapela-group.com (or http://acapela-box.com)
- http://acapela-vaas.com (VaaS means Voice as a Service, and this is a pure web API)
- http://www.ivona.com/en/developer/
- http://www.voiceforge.com/
- https://speechtronic.com

Except for Neospeech, which has a free plan, the others are over my budget... Also, I'm disappointed that Neospeech's API is asynchronous. The API returns a code, whose status you then look up, until you get a url for the result. So it sounds like it's geared towards large amounts of text at a time.

Comment: Thank you very much. Actually, I solved the issue using the Microsoft.Speech assembly from .NET framework, but it is good to know another alternatives :-)

Comment: Good to hear. Also, it turns out the Neospeech's "free" plan actually attaches a demo message to every result, so it's not very useful. Ispeech allows you to do that without having an account, although the api key for that is not very well documented.

Answer (score 23):

I was searching for the exact same thing, I needed pt-BR voice too, and I have just quit using **Google TTS** because it has got some limitations, bugs (with sentence punctuation endings) and no documentation at all.

**I found http://www.voicerss.org/**

It works good for me, it's free, simple API and has the Brazilian pt-BR voice we need.

Comment: Good option, got it integrated in 5 mins.